# Raise ObservableCollection CollectionChanged

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, события, windows-10-mobile

Windows 10 UWP C#

Есть класс из примера MSDN:

```
public class GroupInfoList : List<object>
{
    public object Key { get; set; }
}
```

И есть группированная коллекция которая привязана к `CollectionViewSource` и `ListView`:

```
        ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList> TransactionsCollection = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoList>();
```

Когда я изменяю какие либо элементы то они обновляются в ListView (т.к. вызывается IPropertyChanged), но когда я пытаюсь добавить или удалить из коллекции какой нибудь элемент то ничего не происходит. Событие CollectionChanged не вызывается. Как решить проблему?

Пример удаления из коллекции:

```
        foreach (var x in TransactionsCollection)
        {
            if (x.Key.ToString() == item.displayGroupName)
            {
                x.Remove(x.Find(i => ((Transaction)i).Id == item.Id));
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: В коде удаление из элемента коллекции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не оттуда удаляете.

Вы удаляете не из `TransactionsCollection`, а из `GroupInfoList`. Понятно, что `TransactionsCollection` не отправляет при этом `CollectionChanged`, что ему за дело до подэлементов?

Хотите, чтобы удаление из `x` приводило к отправления `CollectionChanged` — сделайте, чтобы `x` был сам по себе `ObservableCollection<object>` или производным от него.

---

С точки зрения программы, `TransactionsCollection` не «группированная коллекция», а «коллекция групп». Поэтому модификация в вашем примере — не модификация *коллекции*, а модификация *элемента* коллекции.

Comment: А можно его вызвать принудительно?

Comment: @SYL: Можно. Но для этого вам придётся модифицировать `GroupInfoList`, добавить имплементацию `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: Не подскажете что я делаю не так http://pastebin.com/NgdgPq5a

Comment: @SYL: Вы неверно реализовали `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Для события `add` и `remove` вызываются, когда приходит или уходит подписчик на событие. А вы в этот момент почему-то вызываете совершенно другую нотификацию — `PropertyChanged`. Посмотрите, как нужно реализовывать события (примеров масса).

Comment: Спасибо. Унаследовался от `ObservableCollection` и все работает отлично

Comment: @SYL: Угу, или так. Ваш подход даже лучше.